# Xml parser / create a XML DOM Document from a list of XML nodes

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm struggling to find out how to build up a brand new DOM Document in JavaScript, adding it up and loading it from a DOM node list that I already have. All I have found is the stupid looping way, but I'm pretty sure such an architecture has a proper API. But I can't find one!

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) would be useful.  If you want better help, I'd suggest you describe exactly what you're really trying to accomplish, not what solution you want help with, but what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Hello, 

I'm receiving a full xml document from my php service, and I'm retrieving parts of it with the getElementsByTagName() method. Since the tag name is pretty accurate the resulting nodelist contains exactly what I need to pass to a given method. But that method accepts xmldocuments, therefore I'm trying to transform this nodelist into a document containing the nodes of the nodelist.

ClodeNode doesn't returns a domdocument type, but thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Define a base XML document.
var xmlString = "<root>" +
    "<node id='1'>One</node>" +
    "<node id='2'>Two</node>" +
    "<node id='3'>Three</node>" +
    "<node id='4'>Four</node>" +
    "</root>";

// Use jQuery to parse it to a DOM document in a cross-browser fashion.
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString);

// Grab some elements that we will write to a new document.
var node1 = xmlDoc.getElementById("1");
var node3 = xmlDoc.getElementById("3");

// Use jQuery to create the new document, then get a reference
// to the root element.
var newXmlDoc = $.parseXML("<newRoot></newRoot>");
var newRoot = newXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("newRoot")[0];

// Clone the two elements into the new document.
newRoot.appendChild(node1.cloneNode(true));
newRoot.appendChild(node3.cloneNode(true));

// This will write out the text content of the two nodes
// we have cloned into the new document.
// Should write: "OneThree".
document.write(newXmlDoc.documentElement.textContent);
```

Here's the code running in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sajaraki/JnSzK/

It uses a combination of the JavaScript XML DOM implementation as well as jQuery to get around the browser incompatibilities involved in loading and creating XML documents.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your effort, this is indeed the only solution, even though I don't really like the loop idea...

Comment: The question was tagged with `JavaScript` - `Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.`